# Check multiple strings shorter, JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, algorithm, if-statement

I want to check a string if it matches one or more other strings.
In my example i just used 4 possible string values. How can i write this code shorter if i have to check for more values?

```
//Possible example strings: "ce", "c", "del", "log"
let str = "log"; //My input
console.log(str == "log" || str == "del" || str == "c" || str == "ce"); //Return if str has a match
```

Comment: What is the type of possible example strings? Is it an array?

Comment: Better suited for https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use string.match method

```
    let str = "log";

    var re = "^(log|del|c|cd)$";
    var found = str.match(re);

    if (found) ....
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use string `test` here along with an alternation:

```js
var input = "log";
if (/^(?:log|del|c|ce)$/.test(input)) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
else {
    console.log("NO MATCH");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method on an array...

```js
let str = "log";
let arr = ["log","del","c","ce"];
console.log(arr.includes(str));
// Or as a single statement...
console.log(["log","del","c","ce"].includes(str));
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you can use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

```js
let stringToMatch = "log";

let matches = ["ce", "c", "del", "log"];

console.log(matches.indexOf(stringToMatch) !== -1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use an array and its includes() function call:

```
let str = "log";
let criteria = ["log", "del", "c", "ce"];
console.log(criteria.includes(str));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have matching factory and then use it in any place where you need to do multiple matches.

```
const matchingFactory = (string) => new Proxy({}, {
  get(obj, key, receiver) {
     return (() => !!string.match(new RegExp(key, 'i')))()
  }
```

})

And then use it in any module or place in your code in the following way:

```
const _ = matchingFactory('log');
```

Then you could shorten your example to

```
console.log(_.log || _.del || _.c || _.ce); //Return if str has a match
```